# Bot issues with function bot.reply (Discord)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot with the command `!!flip`. I tried this but got this error :

[image: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/362440755350077453/363233799104102401/unknown.png]

So, I then tried `bot.channel.sendmessage` and got this message :

[image: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/362440755350077453/363191581521739776/unknown.png]

Here is my code :

```js
if (message.content === "!!flip") {
    var result = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
    if (result == 1) {
        bot.reply(message, "The coin landed on heads");
    } else if (result == 2) {
        bot.reply(message, "The coin landed on tails");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the errors here, in text format so it's more readable for all of us.

Comment: What library are you using? If it's Discord.JS I'd heavily recommend you read the [docs](https://discord.js.org).

Comment: I can't because I need 10 rep points also yes dicord.js

Comment: Follow @LW001 advice, check the documentation. Or please post you more code.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Firstly, do us all a favor and read the [docs](https://discord.js.org/) before trying to go anywhere with Discord.JS. For this case use `message.reply("The coin landed on Tails")` instead.

Comment: And likewise, `message.channel.sendmessage("Message here")`. (The difference is that, reply() method mentions the user.)